# 4 threads adds to one jlist

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, concurrency, event-dispatch-thread

In my program there are 4 threads that addElemets to a model of a jlist at the same time. This causes jlist to blink, throw excpetions or even crash, because of the too many updates or repaints.

I tried to put some delay that fixed my problem but I was losing to much precious time.

What can I do?

this code simulates my problem:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    for(int o=0; o<2000; o++){
                        model.addElement("add");
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(100);
                        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                            Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }).start();
        }
   }
}).start();
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Swing GUI objects should be constructed and manipulated _only_ on the [event dispatch thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

Comment: How does your model look? What does the addElement method do? If you force the program to repaint every time the addElement method is run it would definitely blink :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The model.addElement("add"); should be something like this:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        listModel.addElement("add");
    }
});
```

This way you make sure that the elements are added under the EDT and not in some random thread.

Answer (score 1):

GUI manipulations should only be performed on the event dispatch thread. Even if you have created many threads, do your non-GUI work on them n fire an actionCommand (or something similar) to manipulate GUI aspects.

You will get to read this warning many times in the Java Docs:
**Swing components are not thread safe**

Answer (score 1):

To avoid too many refresh/repaint you have to do the model updates in the background threads and to copy once into the swing model in the EDT with the technique previously exposed. I suggest to do not use the DefaultListModel but a custom made to dispose of addAll().

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        listModel.addAll( backgroundModel ); // only one fireDataChanged() fired
    }
});
```